# Manually changing browser default theme based on chromium project using its source code

Tags: chromium

I want to **change browser's based on chromium from default theme** gray/black(dark) **to coustom theme** like cyan or other.

I have change it using theme(extension) available on web store which added as default while building browser. But I want it to change it using source code.

I have find some file which contains some relative stuff

[Theme_properties.h](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:chrome/browser/themes/theme_properties.h;l=45;drc=b27071598a6b291a7319d99ce7aa4af81ebc060f)

[browser_theme_pack.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:chrome/browser/themes/browser_theme_pack.cc;l=1540;drc=b27071598a6b291a7319d99ce7aa4af81ebc060f)

[color_id.h](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:ui/color/color_id.h;drc=b27071598a6b291a7319d99ce7aa4af81ebc060f;l=598)